# Get users who belong to groups

Tags: python, django, django-q

I´m trying to get queryset of users who are in a group `Creator` and in a group `Teacher`.

test.py where i send array of groups i want to filter:

```
def test_admin_create_authenticated(self):
    data = {"data": {"alert_type":"system", "text": "UnitTest"}, "filters":{"groups":['Teacher', 'Creator'], "together": True}}
    url = reverse('admin_alerts-list')
    response = self.client.post(url, json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

views.py: Here i would like to make a q_objects which will filter groups by name:

```
if 'groups' in filters:
    print(filters['groups'])
    try: 
        for group in filters['groups']:
            q_objects.add(Q(groups__name=group), variable)
    except:
        q_objects.add(Q(groups=filters['groups']), variable)
```

And then find all users who are in those groups:

```
print(q_objects)
users = User.objects.filter(q_objects)
print(users.query)
print(users)
```

Terminal:

```
['Teacher', 'Creator']
(AND: ('groups__name', 'Teacher'), ('groups__name', 'Creator'))
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "auth_user_groups" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."user_id") INNER JOIN "auth_group" ON ("auth_user_groups"."group_id" = "auth_group"."id") WHERE ("auth_group"."name" = Teacher AND "auth_group"."name" = Creator)
<QuerySet []>
```

Why my q_objects doesn´t work? I have one user who is in those 2 groups.

Comment: You query for a teacher in a group that has a name that is both `Teacher` and `Creator` at the same time. No group can have a name that is two things as the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering for users that belong to *a* group that is named `'Teacher'` and `'Creator'` at the same time. Whereas that should be two (different) groups.

You should filter instead by "chaining" the `.filter(..)` calls here:

```
users = User.objects.all()

for group in filters.get('groups', ()):
    users = users.filter(groups__name=group)
```

at the end of this `for` loop, then `users` contains the `User`s that belong to all the groups in the `filters['groups']`.